# Substract multiple MAX value from view

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

We have a view called: `vu_pohyby`.
It contains all incoming/outgoing goods. It has a lot of records.

It looks like this, for example:

```
  RID         |kod_o |datum_p    |kod_id  |partner |pocet |Cont.n.|storno|cena_dokl
0032000015044 |01    |02.10.2020 |566     |248     |360   |545    |0     |0,250
0292000046277 |      |03.10.2020 |566     |326     |-6    |539    |0     |0,260
0292000046310 |      |04.10.2020 |566     |326     |-6    |533    |0     |0,260
0292000046338 |      |05.10.2020 |566     |325     |-6    |515    |0     |0,260
0292000046350 |      |05.10.2020 |566     |326     |-6    |509    |0     |0,260
          -20 |      |05.10.2020 |566     |        |350   |509    |0     |0,000
                            
Continuous number -> 
(sum (decode(STORNO, 0, decode(L.RID, '-20', 0,l.pocet),0)) over (ORDER BY l.datum_p ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
```

I want to get the difference between prices -> income/outgoing in another table.

So i want to select 2 prices, which are linked to the highest date (datum_p).

I tried, but it's not good:

```
(select price_out from ( 
 select l.kod_id,  --goods
 l.cena_dokl as price_out
from vu_pohyby l --table
where l.storno=0 and l.kod_o is null --canceled=0, l.kod_o->flag=out/incoming
 and substr(l.rid,1,3)='029' -- 029->out
group by l.rid, l.datum_p, l.kod_id, l.cena_dokl
order by l.datum_p desc ) 
aa where aa.kod_id=sklad_karta.id and rownum=1)
-
(select price_inc from ( 
 select l.kod_id,
 l.cena_dokl as price_inc
from vu_pohyby l 
where l.storno=0 
and substr(l.rid,1,3)='003' --003->incoming
group by l.rid, l.datum_p, l.kod_id, l.cena_dokl
order by l.datum_p desc ) 
aa where aa.kod_id=sklad_karta.id and rownum=1)
```

Simplification:

I want to distract 2 prices:

1:...where MAX(datum_P), kod_o=NULL, storno=0 -> In this case **0292000046350** -> **0,26**

2:...where MAX(datum_P), kod_o=01, storno=0 -> In this case **0032000015044** -> **0,25**
Difference: 0,01

How can i solve this in one query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `MAX( cena_dokl ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY datum_p )` to get the value for the latest date and then you want to filter for the price in/price out rows. Something like:

```sql
SELECT kod_id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN kod_o IS NULL THEN datum_p END )
         AS date_most_recent_price_out,
       MAX( CASE WHEN kod_o IS NULL THEN cena_dokl END ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN kod_o IS NULL THEN datum_p END ASC NULLS FIRST
       ) AS most_recent_price_out,
       MAX( CASE WHEN kod_o IS NOT NULL THEN datum_p END )
         AS date_most_recent_price_in,
       MAX( CASE WHEN kod_o IS NOT NULL THEN cena_dokl END ) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN kod_o IS NOT NULL THEN datum_p END ASC NULLS FIRST
       ) AS most_recent_price_in
FROM   vu_pohyby
WHERE  storno=0
AND    (  ( kod_o IS NULL     AND rid LIKE '029%' )
       OR ( kod_o IS NOT NULL AND rid LIKE '003%' ) )
GROUP BY
       kod_id
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE vu_pohyby ( RID, kod_o, datum_p, kod_id, partner, pocet, "Cont.n.", storno, cena_dokl ) AS
SELECT '0032000015044', '01', DATE '2010-10-02', 566, 248,  360, 545, 0, 0.250 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0292000046277', NULL, DATE '2010-10-03', 566, 326,   -6, 539, 0, 0.260 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0292000046310', NULL, DATE '2010-10-04', 566, 326,   -6, 533, 0, 0.260 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0292000046338', NULL, DATE '2010-10-05', 566, 325,   -6, 515, 0, 0.260 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0292000046350', NULL, DATE '2010-10-05', 566, 326,   -6, 509, 0, 0.260 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '          -20', NULL, DATE '2010-10-05', 566, NULL, 350, 509, 0, 0.000 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> KOD_ID | DATE_MOST_RECENT_PRICE_OUT | MOST_RECENT_PRICE_OUT | DATE_MOST_RECENT_PRICE_IN | MOST_RECENT_PRICE_IN
> -----: | :------------------------- | --------------------: | :------------------------ | -------------------:
>    566 | 2010-10-05                 |                   .26 | 2010-10-02                |                  .25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6f0a8bb653d2b308c62162629e62df1)*

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks!